# Node Permission Comparison in two AEM Environmenrs

Tags: python, python-3.x, adobe, aem, aem-6

I wanted to write a Jenkins python job to compare the difference in Node permissions in two different AEM environments. In the Jenkins UI I should be able to configure which environments to compare and which path to compare. I need the output to be in such a way that it should have environment-1 and environment-2, the path that is being compared and the permissions they have.  For Example in the Dev environment, for the path /content/dam/test we have only read permissions and for the same path we have read and write permissions in Stage Environment then the output should be

```
                  **Environment-1**       **Environment-2**
```

**Content/dam/test**       Read                Read & Write

The real question here is how do I retrieve the node permission from the two aem environments and how to compare and filter only the node paths that has difference in permissions?

Comment: I know you are asking for Python, but have you looked at JCR Compare feature from ACS Commons?

Comment: Yes, I know about the JCR Compare. Because of our dispatcher configurations the JCR compare doesn't really work with our environments since it can not crawl to our instances. so every time we want to use JCR compare we have to recreate the two environments to my local and compare. So I wanted to write a jenkins job to retrieve and compare the permissions.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the PageInfo servlet. Example call: http://localhost:4502/libs/wcm/core/content/pageinfo.json?path=/content/we-retail/us/en

You will get a permissions node like this:

```
  "permissions": {
    "modify": true,
    "replicate": true,
    "read": true,
    "create": true,
    "delete": true,
    "acl_read": true,
    "acl_edit": true
  },
```

See: https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-4/sites/developing/using/pageinfo.html for more information.

Comment: It is not that I am unable to get the permissions info, but I wanted to compare permissions in two different environments and output only the nodes that has difference in permissions.